# Unexpected result from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, conditional-statements

I'm new at JavaScript, but if anyone can tell me what i missing I would be grateful.

Basically, I'm trying to test the large value from two input. Here is what I have done so far:

```
$('#than_stock_submit').click(function() {
    var pur_rate = $('#pur_rate input').val(),
        sell_rate = $('#sell_rate input').val(),
        msg_div = $('#sell_rate .msg');

    if(greater_than(sell_rate, pur_rate, msg_div)==false){return false}
});

function greater_than(a, b, msg_div){
    msg_div.show().html( '' );
    if(a > b){
        msg_div.show().html( '<p class="success">Sell Rate is good</p>' );
        return true;
    } else {
        msg_div.show().html( '<p class="error">Sell Rate should be increased</p>' );
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have checked with several values. When i tested with the value smaller than 1000 and similar both values like b=500 and a=5000 or b=100 and a=1000, then its working. Other values are not working.

Other tested values are:

1. a=751, b=750 and result=true
2. a=0751, b=750 and result=false
3. a=551, b=750 and result=false
4. a=1051, b=750 and result=false
5. a=7500, b=750 and result=true
6. a=6000, b=600 and result=true

I also checked with console like:     console.log(a + b);

The results of console window is like 1000750(when value is like a=1000 & b=750) or 0752750(when value is like a=0752 & b=750).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more robust solution (what you're doing is a string comparison and not a number comparison).

```
function greater_than(a,b) {
  // first, convert both passed values to numbers
  // (or at least try)
  var nA = new Number(a),
      nB = new Number(b);

  // check if they were converted successfully.
  // isNaN = is Not a Number (invalid input)
  if (!isNan(nA) && !isNaN(nB)) {
    // now go ahead and perform the check
    msg_div.empty().show();
    if (nA > nB) {
      $('<p>',{'class':'success'})
        .text('Sell Rate is good')
        .appendTo(msg_div);
      return true;
    } else {
      $('<p>',{'class':'error'})
        .text('Sell Rate should be increased')
        .appendTo(msg_div);
    }
  }
  // In case you wanted to handle showing an error for
  // invalid input, you can uncomment the following lines
  // and take the necessary action(s)
  else{
    /* one of them was not a number */
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that I used jQuery to build the `<p>` that you add. I also used [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) instead of assingning `.html('')`.

And some documentation:

- [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.
Can you tell me why you use 
$('<p>',{'class':'success'})
        .text('Sell Rate is good')
        .appendTo(msg_div);
 instead of
msg_div.show().html( '<p class="success">Sell Rate is good</p>' );

and .empty() instead of assingning .html('')

Comment: It's much safer to build DOM using the supplied methods than to supply explicit HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the strings to numbers before comparing (they become strings when using `.val()`). Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`:

```
function greater_than(a, b, msg_div){
    a = parseInt(a, 10);
    b = parseInt(b, 10);
    // etc
```

Comment: And links to [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (`parseInt`  for whole numbers, `parseFloat` with numbers that could contain decimal numbers)

Comment: but can you tell me, what is for the 10?

Comment: The second argument is radix. JavaScript has some C legacy behaviors, if you pass f.ex `parseInt(03)` it can interpret this as an *octal value* in some ECMA versions. Passing `10` as second argument ensures decimal interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings and `"1000">"99"` is false.

The solution is to first parse your numbers using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) :

```
 var pur_rate = parseFloat($('#pur_rate input').val());
```

or

```
 var pur_rate = parseInt($('#pur_rate input').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading an input value returns string. So if you compare string to string, it's an ASCII comparison, not a numerical one. Please use `parseInt(value, 10);` Never forget the radix! ;)